# Function that computes rk method/no plotting

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, lambda

```
import math 
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
from numpy import linspace

tmax=10.0
n=2000
G=4
D=-1
m=2
t=np.linspace (0,400,n+1)
phi=10
dphi=delta=phi_dot=np.linspace(0,400,n+1)

def f(delta_dot,t):
    return ((G)*(D*delta+m))

def iterate (func,phi,delta,tmax,n):
    dt=tmax/(n-1)
    t=0.0

    for i in range(n):
        phi,delta = func (phi,delta,t,dt)
        t += dt

    return phi

def rk_iter(phi,delta,t,dt):
    k1=f(t,phi)
    k2=f(t+dt*0.5,phi+k1*0.5*dt)
    k3=f(t+dt*0.5,phi*k2*0.5*dt)
    k4=f(t*dt,phi*k3*dt)

    delta +=dt*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6
    k1=k2=k3=k4=delta=phi_dot
    phi += dt*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6
    return phi,delta

runge_kutta = lambda delta, phi,tmax,n:iterate(rk_iter,delta,phi,tmax,n)

def plot_result (delta,phi,tmax,n):
 dt=tmax/(n-1)
 error_rk=[]
 r_rk=[]
 t=0.0

 phi=phi_rk=phi
 delta=delta_rk=delta

 for i in range(n):
     phi_rk,delta_rk=rk_iter(phi_rk,delta_rk,t,dt=tmax/(n-1))
     t+=dt
     _plot("error.png","Error","time t", "error e",error_rk)

def _plot(title,xlabel,ylabel,rk):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.title(title)
plt.ylabel(ylabel)
plt.xlabel(xlabel)

plt.plot(rk,"r--",label="Runge-Kutta")

plt.legend(loc=4)
plt.grid(True)
plt.plot(runge_kutta,t)


print "runge_kutta=", runge_kutta(phi,delta,tmax,n)
print "tmax=",t
```

I have no idea how to get the function `plt.show()` to work. What do I have to do to open a plot window?

Comment: So what is `f` here?

Comment: Your indentation needs a lot of work to fix. Can you perhaps re-paste your original code, select it all, and use the `{}` button on the toolbar to properly format it instead of trying to indent by hand?

Comment: I'm guessing `f` is an instance of some Class and you're trying to call it instead of a method.

Comment: f is part of the runge kutta formula:k_j=f(t_n+h,y_n...

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined `f`; instead, `f` is being imported from matplotlib by the statement `from matplotlib import *`:

```
In [10]: import matplotlib

In [11]: matplotlib.f
Out[11]: Forward: "a"

In [12]: matplotlib.f(1,1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-5843007d7dbe> in <module>()
----> 1 matplotlib.f(1,1)

TypeError: __call__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

You will save yourself many headaches like this in the future if you *never use the `*` form of the import statement* in your scripts.  For example, instead of `from math import *`, use one of these two forms:

```
import math

# Now refer to math.sin, math.pi, etc.
```

or, explicilty import only the names that you will use:

```
from math import sin, pi
```

Answer (score 0):

At no point do you call the `plot_result` procedure. And even if you called it, you do not fill the `rk` and `error_rk` lists. You could simply use the result from the `runge_kutta` call,...

As commented in the other, duplicate post, you define the system equation as `f(y,t)` but use it as `f(t,y)`.

There is some confusion in the usage of `delta`, sometimes it is the integration variable, sometimes the rk4-step update.

In the rk4-step, there are some misplaced multiplications where there should be additions. And the line

```
    k1=k2=k3=k4=delta=phi_dot
```

is complete nonsense and invalidates the previous computations and makes the rk4-update in the next step meaningless.

Remove the imports of math and linspace, neither is used in the code. Move the aliasing of plt to the top and merge it with the unnecessary import of matplotlib.